# How to use the reusable components in SPFx projects

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, reusable, office-ui-fabric-react, reusable-content

I am working in a SharePoint Framework (SPFx) project in Online version. We have created two separate projects, one is main project and another one is common project. The common project will contain the custom components which will be reusable across the projects.

But i got stuck in including the common component in the Main project. Any one please suggest the solution to include the component under the common project into the main project component.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: is your common project a yeoman generated SPFx project or a simple javascript/typescript, gulp,webpack project  ?

Comment: It is a yeoman generated SPFx Project

Comment: By component do you mean React component ? An option is to create the common project as a simple JS project, bundle it up and refer in your main SPFx project. This way you can have react components and common in a separate JS bundle.

Comment: Actually it is a React component